# MS Ribbon: draw button icon from code

Tags: c++, button, icons, ribbon

I try to create MS Ribbon button icon form code.
I created CImage with 32 bpp.

```
CImage img;
img.Create(size, size, 32, CImage::createAlphaChannel);
```

Then I used this image like hdc for bitmap:

```
HDC hdc = CImageDC(img);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, cx, cy, hdcMem, sx, sy, SRCCOPY);
```

Finally, I used UIRibbonImageFromBitmapFactory and set result into property:

```
IUIImage* pImg;
CComPtr<IUIImageFromBitmap> pifb;
pifb.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UIRibbonImageFromBitmapFactory);
pifb->CreateImage(img, UI_OWNERSHIP_TRANSFER, &pImg);
UIInitPropertyFromImage(key, pImg, ppropvarNewValue);
```

As result all functions finished successfully but button icon is empty!!!

I used these requirements http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316921(v=vs.85).aspx
Are additional requirements needed for button icon?

Comment: Make sure you deselect the image bitmap from the DC before passing it to `CreateImage`.

Comment: I have added selection. Result is the same. But thank you for pointing on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to convert to HBITMAP first, and then use the framework's factory to produce the IUIImage:

```
// Load the bitmap from the resource file.
CImage img;
hr = img.Load(pszResource);
if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

HBITMAP hbm = (HBITMAP) img.Detach();
if (hbm)
{
    // Use the factory implemented by the framework to produce an IUIImage.
    hr = m_pifbFactory->CreateImage(hbm, UI_OWNERSHIP_TRANSFER, ppimg);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        DeleteObject(hbm);
    }
}
```

Then you can add the image to the button, as in

```
// Set the image as the new property value for the button.
hr = UIInitPropertyFromImage(UI_PKEY_LargeImage, pImg, ppropvarNewValue);
```

Good luck!